# Row numbers appear to be forced when inline editing is turned on for a lightning data table

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am wondering if I have found a minor bug with LWCs. I have noticed that row numbers in a data table are turned on if one of the columns is set to "Editable" even if the "show-row-number-column" isn't present.

I have created a simple playground (linked below) to illustrate this potential bug. Note, that "show-row-number-column" isn't on the data table yet the row numbers are displayed. As soon as you set all of the columns to editable:false the row number will go away.

This may be the expected behavior, but I couldn't find it documented anywhere. Of course, this isn't a big deal at all, but for my specific use case, it does make it a little confusing for the end-user.

```
 <!-- Note how "show-row-number-column" isn't selected 
    yet the row numbers are still dislayed -->
    <lightning-datatable
            key-field="id"
            data={data}
            columns={columns}>
    </lightning-datatable>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/qRYnNX2ci/6/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an expected behavior and is [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation):

> By making a column editable, the `show-row-number-column` attribute is always `true` and the number column is displayed.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely didn't recall that line in the error section. It does make sense that the row numbers are required since the errors reference the numbers.